# Setting prompt for MariaDB 10.2 in my.cnf?

Tags: mariadb

I'd like to set the default prompt on MariaDB across all our database servers for everyone. I assume this would be best done in my.cnf. I can set the prompt in a session, but when I try to add something like `prompt=name[/d]>/_` in my.cnf, MariaDB fails to start an complains about it.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Was that in the `[mysql]` section (not `[mysqld]`)?  Perhaps you mean backslashes instead of slashes?

Comment: Check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) - it's probably what works on MariaDB also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> across all our database servers for everyone

This is a function of the client. You can't set it on the server. MySQL ships with a client, and a server. The client determines the prompt. There is nothing you can do on the server to fix that. The client could be something totally different that has for its prompt

```
L33tHAX\###->#
```

You can see the code here [`construct_prompt()`](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/client/mysql.cc#L5137). Nothing there hits the server. That said, it gets set here in the [main](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/client/mysql.cc#L1135)

```
default_prompt = my_strdup(getenv("MYSQL_PS1") ? 
                 getenv("MYSQL_PS1") : 
                 "\\N [\\d]> ",MYF(MY_WME));
current_prompt = my_strdup(default_prompt,MYF(MY_WME));
```

So it would seem you could set it through the `MYSQL_PS1` environmental variable.

Comment: Thank you, this explains my problems. I basically have to set it in the [mysql] section or the environment variable of each potential client location.